# Adsense ads do not show in Safari after upgrading to OS X Lion

Tags: osx-lion, safari

After I installed OS X 10.7 (Lion) I do not see any Adsense ads in Safari. I also updated my Macbook air, and there they still appear. What could be causing this? As I have also Ads on my own pages, I would like to see if they are still there. I did not installed any Adsense blocker.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was causing the problem - it was a divx extension that stopped working properly after updating to Lion.